# Use the groupby method from pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with this code:

```
#obs is a dataframe with a column ['id']
def prova(df):
    test.append(len(df))
    return
test=[]
obs2.groupby('id').apply(prova)

print sum(test)
print len(obs2)
```

output

```
98333
98329
```

Why are the outputs different?
Thanks :)

EDIT
I noticed that if I remove the first element of test the result turn right

Comment: Can you add a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Without knowing more about the dataframe `obs2`, it's difficult to answer your question.